# ajax CORS with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain, cors

I want to do cross domain ajax calls with **custom header and cookies**.
I did it with CORS which works with Chrome, Firefox and IE 10 and 11.

How can I get it to work in IE 9?

Note:
**I need custom headers and cookies.**

Answer (score 2):

If your request are just GET and POST, you can use the XDomainRequest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

There is a plugin for jQuery $.ajax: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

If you want to use the full CORS capabilities (es: call REST services with a backbone.js fronted, use PUT and DELETE methods) sadly you cannot support IE 9.

Comment: I have custom headers and cookies which XDomainRequest doesn't support according to the blog you linked **3. No custom headers may be added to the request 5. No authentication or cookies will be sent with the request** "